# Assigning rubberband as polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgsrubberband

I am trying to display a rubberband on my mapCanvas in QGIS but it seems that `setToMapCanvas` will only accept a `QRect` object. I am trying to show on the canvas the visible area of a maplayout with a rotation. I tried rotating the `QRect` with `QTransform` but I can only get the rotation to rotate from 0,0 (i.e. Top Left Corner) or a wildly random location depending on scale. Or I transform the `QRect` with a rotation and return it to a `PolygonF` only to find no way to set it to the map canvas with rubberband.

When I try to return the Polygon I get `TypeError: setToMapCanvas(self, QTransform): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPolygonF'`
When I try to transform the `QRect` I get `TypeError: setToMapCanvas(self, QTransform): argument 1 has unexpected type 'transform'`

```
mtp = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().mapToPixel()
p1 = mtp.transform(QgsPoint(rect.left(), rect.top()))
p2 = mtp.transform(QgsPoint(rect.right(), rect.bottom()))
rect = QTransform().mapToPolygon(QRect(p1.x(), p1.y(), p2.x() - p1.x(), p2.y() - p1.y()))
rect_r = rect.rotate(45)
return QPolygonF(rect_r)
```

When I use this code to rotate the rubberband

```
self.__cleanup()
extent = self.mapitem.extent()
center = self.iface.mapCanvas().extent().center()
self.corner = QPointF(center.x() - 0.5 * extent.width(), center.y() - 0.5 * extent.height())
self.rect = QRectF(self.corner.x(), self.corner.y(), extent.width(), extent.height())
self.mapitem.setExtent(QgsRectangle(self.rect))
self.rubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.iface.mapCanvas(), QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
self.rubberband.setToCanvasRectangle(self.__canvasRect(self.rect))
#    tveinot 20200122 set the rubberband rotation and rotation point
self.rubberband.setTransformOriginPoint((0.5 * self.rect.width()),(0.5 * self.rect.height()))
self.rubberband.setRotation(self.dialogui.spinbox_Rotation.value())
self.rubberband.setColor(QColor(127, 127, 255, 127))
```

The rotation point varies depending on my scale and location.
If I change `(0.5 * self.rect.width())` to `center.x()/y()` respectively 1 degree of rotations sends the rectangle off screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `setToMapCanvas` method in PyQGIS. Do you mean `setToCanvasRectangle` or a custom method which you've defined? And there is no `setToMapCanvas` method in the script above.

Comment: Yes sorry, setToCanvasRectangle is what I am using in the posted code, sorry for the description mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth, I have not been able to get the `setToCanvasRectangle()` method of `QgsRubberBand` class to work. Even when I pass it a `QRect` object, my code runs without error but the rubber band is not shown. I can get a good result using the `setToGeometry()` method though.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do with the rubber band class, I think that the minimal snippet below should help you. This is just for testing in the console but you should be able to adapt fairly easily for a plugin.

```
rb = QgsRubberBand(iface.mapCanvas(),QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
rect = iface.mapCanvas().extent() # QgsRectangle object
geom = QgsGeometry().fromRect(rect) #QgsGeometry object
# rotate geometry 30 degrees clockwise around centroid
geom.rotate(30.00, geom.centroid().asPoint())
# set rubber band to geometry
rb.setToGeometry(geom)
rb.setStrokeColor(QColor('red'))
rb.setWidth(3)
rb.show()

# run line below to reset (hide) the rubber band
# rb.reset()
```

This gives the result below.

Map canvas before running the code:

[image]

After running code and zooming out to see canvas extent from previous screen rotated 30 degrees around centroid and shown as a rubber band item:

[image]

Comment: So I passed the QRect from the first part of the code as Rect to the rubberband part of the code using rb_object = QgsGeometry().fromRect(self.__canvasRect(self.rect) *Which should be the QRect return created from the earlier code" and I get the error "p1 = mtp.transform(QgsPoint(rect.left(), rect.top()))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'left'" Yet my python console says left is an attribute. It seems like the error is saying I have left as a attribute as long as I do not try to convert the result to a Geometry...

Comment: `QgsGeometry().fromRect()` method takes a `QgsRectangle` object not a `QRect`. And it looks like the first part of your code returns a QpolygonF, so I'm a bit confused about what you are doing. What is it exactly you are trying to show with the rubber band?

Comment: I can't help getting the impression that your current code is more complicated than it needs to be...

Comment: To answer your first comment, What I am trying to do in full is there is a plugin for QGIS called insta print and I use it quite a bit. I posted a feature request in 2017 for adding a rotation so you could rotate the print view and have it correlate with your chosen layout. So after taking some python courses and gaining some experience I decided to try and addd it myself, with the intention of sharing the code of course. I managed to; add the spinbox, pass the value to the layout rotation, refresh the rubberband on value change, and rotate the rubberband. Stuck on rotating it properly.

Comment: To your second comment, Fair enough, I completely understand. Where I am trying to add a feature to a pre-existing plugin there is some additional complication/nuances to contend with. This part is proving to be the most difficult, but it should also be the final bit. None the less I still do appreciate you taking the time to respond, it has opened up some approaches.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not familiar with that plugin. I'm on the road at the moment and not in front of the computer, but when I get a chance I will try to check it out and have a look at the source code to see if I can help a bit more. Best of luck with your efforts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103934/discussion-between-tyler-veinot-and-ben-w).